# Need regex to find last part of input name javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following input name:

```
fw_options[testgradient][background-gradient-start-color]
```

I need to get the last part of the name:

```
background-gradient-start-color
```

I was able to do this with this messy code:

```
name.replace('][','-').replace(/^[^-]*-/,'').replace(']','').replace('[','');
```

However, I forgot that the name can also look like this:

```
fw_options[header_boxstyle][background][background-gradient-start-color]
```

So, I ended up with the wrong string:

```
backgroundbackground-gradient-start-color
```

Can someone please simplify this for me, so that I don't have to use multiple replaces?

I need to get the last part without matching `background-gradient-start-color` *literally*, since I have multiple names that I need to find with the same regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract that with a regex and a capturing group:

```
\[([^\]]*)\]$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kA5vR6/2)

The value will be in the Group 1.

```js
var re = /\[([^\]]*)\]$/g; 
var str = 'fw_options[testgradient][background-gradient-start-color]';
    
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m[1];
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Or a non-regex way with `lastIndexOf` (crude, without error checking):

```js
var str = "fw_options[testgradient][background-gradient-start-color]";
var ido = str.lastIndexOf("[");
var idc = str.lastIndexOf("]");
alert(str.substring(ido+1,idc));
```

Comment: My pleasure. Also, I added a non-regex method for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You could use other tricks as well:

```js
var input = 'fw_options[testgradient][background-gradient-start-color]';
alert(input.replace(/\]/g, '').split(/\[/g).pop());
```